# Question about loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I tried this loop, but isn't working (Syntax errors).
What is the correct way to do it? up+i  doesn't work for example.

```
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            up+i = function() {
                base.refresh("Field"+i, $t+i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `up+i` supposed to be?

Comment: up0, up1, up2, and so on

Comment: `up+i = function()` isn't valid Javascript, that's why you get syntax error

Comment: Can you explain not only what `up+i` is supposed to be, but also what `base` and `$t` refer to, since they're not defined in the scope of the loop nor in the scope of the inner function?

Comment: @Fel that isn't really going to work. Have you considered using an array instead? e.g.: `up[i] = ...`

Comment: Ah. You can't do `up+i`, but you can do `window['up' + i]`. Though I don't recommend it

Comment: when i make +i, i  want up1, Field1, $t1 at the same time, to avoid ten pieces of code where the unique choice that changes is the numeration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is around this line

```
up+i = function() {
```

The expression `up+i` produces a value, not a variable, and a place which can be assigned to.  Were you trying instead to assign into an array?  If so change it to the following

```
up[i] = function() {
```

**EDIT**

OP clarified that the intent is to create 10 named functions.  In that case there needs to be an object to hang them off of.  I'll call it root for an example

```
var root = {};
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  root['up' + i] = function() { 
    base.refresh("Field"+i, $t+i);
  };
}
```

Additionally right now the function is capturing a single `i` meaning all instances of the function will have the same value for `i`.  To prevent this use a separate function to capture the value.

```
var root = {};
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  root['up' + i] = function(arg) { 
    return function() { base.refresh("Field"+arg, $t+arg); };
  } (i);
}
```

Comment: This isn't right, see the second comment for what he was trying to do.  He was trying to make 10 functions, not an array of 10 functions.

Comment: @Nick, when clarifications to questions are added after the fact it's much better to comment to notify people and then later down vote not immediately

Comment: @jared the comment that i posted to Nick also applies to your suggestion.

Comment: @Fel what did you intend for `$t` to reference? It's hard to help unless we know the intent of that value

Comment: if i use $t+i i get the error, but this.  $t0, $t1, $t2 works well. Probably the best choice is separate pieces of code... thanks anyway.

Comment: @JaredPar where is that rule written, what you were showing wasn't correct, and it was pretty apparent even with out the commend, that he was trying to accomplish the same.

Comment: @Nick it's more of a guideline than a rule. Especially when questions are ambiguous in nature.

Comment: Questions that are ambiguous should be closed, not encouraged.

Comment: @Nick I strongly disagree. People who ask ambiguous questions are often the newer and more confused users. Shutting them out with "closed" does nothing but discourage them from using the site.

Comment: @Jared you should listen to the last SO podcast #4 Jeff and Joel actually advocated this to keep the community clean, because SO is beyond the hand holding process as a community.

Answer (score 1):

The code responsible for looping works. Just see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7aZLv/ (warning! opens 10 alert boxes one after another)

**EDIT:**

You can create global functions like that: http://jsfiddle.net/7aZLv/1/

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    window['up'+i] = function(){
        alert('test');
    }
}

up3(); // will make alert appear
```

The error happened because you assignment expression was incorrect (you assigned value to *expression*, not a *variable* how it should be assigned).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should just be

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        up = function() {
            base.refresh("Field"+i, $t+i);
        }
    }
```

? We need lots of information to help you, what is up supposed to be, what are you trying to accomplish? What syntax errors are you getting?

Comment: He wants it to generate up1, up2, up3, up4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an expression on the left hand side of an assignment. is `up+i` supposed to be pointer arithmetic? if so, there are no pointers in javascript. i cannot tell what you are trying to do, but the first thing to do would be to change `up+i = function() { ...}` to `up = function() {...}` or else get a new variable to assign it too.

Answer (score 0):

Many errors in your code.

> up
>   is string?
>   $t
>   what is this?

maybe like this?

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
var new_func = 'up' + i;
        new_func = function() {
            base.refresh("Field"+i, $t+i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create individual variables for the functions, you can add them to an array.

```
var ups;

for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    ups.push(function() {
        base.refresh("Field"+i, $t+i);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
   window["up" +i] = function() {
      base.refresh("Field"+i, $t+i);
   }
}
```

This will add the functions to the `window` object so that you can make calls like this after it:

```
up0();
up1();
// etc
```

Comment: ReferenceError: $t is not defined. But if i use $t1 directly the error go away.

Comment: Don't know it is your syntax.